In what sense is this column-sum=1, row-sum=2 matrix even, since the imaginary part of its Fourier vanishes?
Consider the following matrix
$$M := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
and let $\hat M$ denote the 5-dimensional Fourier transform of $M$.
Another way to represent $M$ is by the string "ACBBCADEED", where if the $i$-th letter of the string is the $k$-th letter of the alphabet, then, $M^k_i=1$, and $M^j_i=0$ for any $j \neq k$.
Weirdly, $\text{Imag}\left(\hat M^i_j\right)=0$. I was wondering, in what sense is $M$ even? Typically when you take the $N$-dimensional fourier transform of a function, and you get a $0$ imaginary component, then the function is guaranteed even. But in this case, the linear transformation given by $M$ cannot be even, since it is linear: $M\cdot(v) = -M\cdot(-v)$, but even would require $Mx = M(-x)$ which cannot be satisfied as $M$ is linear. So, I was wondering, is there a sense in which $M$ is even, or more specifically, in what sense is the matrix $M$ even?

Whoever said a function whose Fourier transform has real part $0$ is even?  For example, try the odd function $f(x) = x \exp(-x^2)$, whose Fourier transform is
$\hat{f}(p) = - \frac{i \sqrt{\pi}}{2} p \exp(-p^2/4)$.

@RobertIsrael You're right, I got even/odd mixed up. I believe the imaginary part of the FT vanishes if and only if the function is even. And an odd function would have a zero real part. It does of course make sense that $-Mv=M(-v)$, however there are other matrices generated in a similar fashion which have non-zero real part: For example the matrix corresponding to "ABBACEDDEC" has nonzero imaginary and real parts of various components, but that would also be odd. I suppose it is just a reflection of the structure of the matrix itself that the real part vanishes.

I apologize for the unorganized question, I'll have to reconsider some of the Fourier transform theorems and literature in order to come back to this one with some kind of sense. Cheers

Fixed the body of the question - The imaginary part of $M$ is the one that vanishes, not the real part.

@RobertIsrael I believe I figured out what makes this matrix "Even", and posted an answer. I fact checked the answer with all possible Fouriers of matrix of a similar kind and always found this property to hold even for $n=11$.

Once you consider the cyclic representation of $M$ using letters ABCDE, the evenness can be described as follows. Between any two of the same letter, the string on the inside, and the string on the outside, are palindromes. That is, they are the same forwards and backwards between any two letters.

$A$: $\quad CBBC, \quad DEED$
$B$: $\quad CADEEDAC,\quad  \epsilon$
$C$: $\quad BB,\quad  ADEEDA$
$D$: $\quad EE, \quad ACBBCA$
$E$: $\quad DACBBCAD,\quad  \epsilon$

Notice that between any two letters, there is a palindromic string on the inside and outside. This is exactly the evenness which makes the imaginary part of the Fourier transform of the associated matrix zero.
